# Setting a Graphical Image for Neofetch - ImageMagick Error - Kitty - Neofetch Returns Blank

Tags: linux, imagemagick, kitty

When I try to use `kitty +kitten icat`, I receive the following error:

```
➜  ~ kitty +kitten icat image.jpeg                   
Failed to open image: image.jpeg with error: identify: no decode delegate for this image format `JPEG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/741.
```

Yes image.jpeg is the name of the file I' trying to open and it is in my home directory.

I am able to open an image in `Terminology` with `tycat`. But I am not able to do it with `Neofetch`.

I've tried numerous different terminal, and messing around with `ImageMagik`. I have done research on this and havne't been able to find a solution. I have tried this with multiple image types and images. Nothing has worked so far. The `neofetch` always returns blank.

Comment: Does it open directly in Imagemagick?

Comment: Could you please elaborate.

Comment: Does `convert your_image.suffix your_image.gif` work in command line Imagemagick.

Comment: No. I get this error:
➜  ~ convert image.png image.gif
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/741.
convert: no images defined `image.gif' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3342.
➜  ~

Comment: What do you get from `convert -version`?  Does it include PNG in the list of Delegates. If not, you need to install the libpng delegate and recompile IM or get a binary that includes PNG

Comment: Here is the output:
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-59 Q16-HDRI x86_64 20828 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI
Delegates (built-in):
Compiler: gcc (12.2)
The delegate png is not shown.
`libpng` is already installed.

Comment: You have no delegates. You must have installed from source. You need to install from a binary so that you get all the delegates. Or install delegates, then install from source linking to the delegates.

Comment: Strange. I've installed the binary as well as from source. What are the delegates that I need to install?

Comment: Here is what I have though not all are needed. `bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype gslib gvc heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png ps raw rsvg tiff webp x xml zlib`. I think you need at minimum: `bzlib fontconfig freetkype gslib jpeg lams png tiff xml zlib`.  What do you get from the version that you installed from binary?  Where did you get your binary and on what platform/os?

Comment: How do I view the version of the binary install?

Comment: `path_to_version/convert -version`. First find all the versions you have and their paths using `type convert`. If using IM 7 rather than IM 6, then replace `convert` with `magick`

Comment: 7.1.0-59 I think. I ran both commands /sbin/convert -version as well as for magick. They both had the same out put. I installed the delegates that you said were required except for the ones that broke other dependencies according to my package manage (xbps). The delegates list is still blank.

Comment: After installing delegates, you need to recompile Imagemagick.  If you did not install delegates in a way that Imagemagick can find them, then it won't work. Be sure your $PATH includes both  the location of imagemagick and the location of your delegates. Also if a delegate needs other delegates, then those must be installed. Check the config.log of each delegate to find out what is wrong. Also the config.log of Imagemagick.